# Trying to install gem devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am having a problem adding the gem file: `gem 'devise'`.  When I add it to sublime and then go to the terminal and do `bundle install`, I get an error.  This is what I get:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

An error occured while installing bcrypt (3.1.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.7'` succeeds before bundling.  (I have no idea what this means)
```

I am working on the One Month Rails course following the video tutorials.

Comment: are you using OSX? RVM or RBENV? what does your setup look like

Comment: OSX.  What do you mean by "what does your setup look like"?

Comment: @Mike_Code_Novice we need to know your OS, and how you installed Ruby

Comment: ruby1.9.3p194  When I input rails -v on the command line, I get: Could not find gem 'devise (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.  But when I run bundle install is when I get the error listed in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Native Extensions, in short, are a connection between a rubygem and some non-ruby components, usually some C code or library. For further reading on what exactly goes on when building native extensions [this](http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/10/31/dont-be-terrified-of-building-native-extensions) blog post by Pat Shaughnessy walks through the process.

To address your question, few things could be causing this problem, but the most likely reason is that you require Command Line Tools installed within OSX. If XCode is already installed, run the below command on the command line to install the tools. If XCode is not installed, install the latest version of XCode, restart your terminal, and then run the below command.

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Once you've got the command line tools installed you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.  I'm reading through blog post to see if there is something in there I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your ruby development library isn't installed
install the ruby 1.9-dev package or similar dev package, and try again else you could use rvm.