# Error Installing Gem 'devise' ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm working on my first ruby on rails course, building an application.  Below is the error I am getting in the terminal when running the bundle install command.  I am trying to add the gem 'devise'.  I have no idea how to get past this error.  Thanks!

```
Installing bcrypt (3.1.7) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for ruby/util.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:14:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7/ext/mri/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing bcrypt (3.1.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Put `You have to install development tools first.` in the search box at the top of the page and you will find a whole load of questions and solutions.  Hopefully one of them will help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to install gem devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551014/trying-to-install-gem-devise)

Comment: Why you created question again? you have one question about it [Trying to install gem devise](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23551014/1297435). Please read this [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: First time on stack overflow, comments/answers were not solving problem.  Thought I'd add it again with more info of the error.  Thanks for the heads up on what to do if I'm not getting answers on questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missing gcc if you use homebrew

`brew tap homebrew/dupes`

then

`brew install apple-gcc42`

on linux centos/fedora:

`yum install gcc`

on linux ubuntu:

`apt-get install build-essential`

Please update if it helps you.

Comment: I do not use homebrew.  Are you saying I should install it?

Comment: Yes install homebrew then gcc like i wrote above it will solve your problem, please update.

Comment: thank you very much! I finally got it to work.  I also had to follow this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225312/brew-doctor-gives-out-warnings  as I was getting an error when running brew doctor.